# Apply different cell properties depending on section

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

following code works properly but it applies same cell text to all sections. How could I apply selection case also depending on section? Thank you.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;         
    }

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"English";
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Chinese";
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Japanese";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `indexPath.section` to get the section number, just like how you're using `indexPath.row` for the row number.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for the `indexPath.section` and also `indexPath.row`:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {

    if (indexPath.row) {

        ...
    }

} else if (indexPath.section == 1)

    if (indexPath.row) {

        ...
    }

} else if ...
```